# Generate vector from comparison

Tags: r

I like to generate a vector containing 0s and 1s from a comparison of a vector with the elements of a list. I 
have the following vector:

```
functions=c("abline", "as.numeric", "attach", "data.frame", "ddply", "mean")
```

This "functions" vector now should be comared to a list of vectors containing a subset of this vector. The list looks like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "data.frame"

[[2]]
[1] "data.frame" "ddply"      "mean"      

[[3]]
[1] "data.frame" "abline"      "attach"      "mean"
...
```

As a result I would like to produce a vector following the order and length of the "functions" vector containing a 1 for each element matching the "functions" vector and an 0 for not available. All of those i would like to put into a dataframe. For this three list elements this result would look something like the following:

```
    "abline" "as.numeric" "attach" "data.frame"  "ddply"  "mean"
1      0          0          0           1          0       0
2      0          0          0           1          1       1
3      1          0          1           1          0       1
```

Has anybody an idea how I could achieve this?

Best Sab.

Comment: First step is `lapply(listofvectors, function(z)vectoroffunctions %in% z + 0)`

Comment: @danas.zuokas Technically you're right. Still, using `as.numeric()` is a more clear way of indicating you convert logic to numeric than adding `+ 0`. I prefer readibility above hacking, unless you really need to save that microsecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the data

```
functions=c("abline", "as.numeric", "attach", "data.frame", "ddply", "mean")

mylist <- list(
  c("data.frame"),
  c("data.frame","ddply","mean"),
  c("data.frame","abline","attach","mean")
)
```

Then you could simply do:

```
> solution <- lapply(mylist,function(i) as.numeric(functions %in% i))

> mydf <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,solution))

> names(mydf) <- functions

> mydf
  abline as.numeric attach data.frame ddply mean
1      0          0      0          1     0    0
2      0          0      0          1     1    1
3      1          0      1          1     0    1
```

Comment: One thing I noticed. The mydf is still a list! I can not convert it to dataframe somehow. typeof(as.dataframe(mydf)) or typeof(data.frame(mydf)) still give me back "list" and I cannot assign row names. Any idea about that? Best Sab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an nested `sapply`:

```
list <- list("data.frame",c("data.frame","ddply","mean"),c("data.frame","abline","attach","mean"))

sapply(functions,function(x) sapply(list,function(y) as.numeric(x%in%y)))
     abline as.numeric attach data.frame ddply mean
[1,]      0          0      0          1     0    0
[2,]      0          0      0          1     1    1
[3,]      1          0      1          1     0    1
```

Or just a single one, if you use `factor` and `table`:

```
do.call("rbind",lapply(list,function(x) table(factor(x,levels=functions))))
     abline as.numeric attach data.frame ddply mean
[1,]      0          0      0          1     0    0
[2,]      0          0      0          1     1    1
[3,]      1          0      1          1     0    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried also your solution but I have the same problem as with the above solution. I end up with a list element which seems to bee not convertable to a data.frame.